# How can I calculate age in MS Excel if the year of birth is provided in one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

No DOB, only year of birth data is there in one column, need to calculate corresponding age in the other column based on today’s year/date.

Comment: Do you mean, you can calculate age only approximately (~1 year)?

Comment: Can you show the formula you've tried please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter this in cell `B2` and drag this **down** to other cells in column `B`:

```
=IF(A1="", "", YEAR(NOW())-A1)
```

**Assumptions:**

- The year of birth is in column A.
- Calculating the **approximate age** based only on the year.
- You want the approximate age displayed in column B.
- You want to leave the result blank if the corresponding year of birth is not entered.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's formula for current year

```
=YEAR(TODAY())
```

To get your desired result, simply deduct the year of the DOB from the above formula to get the age of each individual.

Comment: How to do that deduction. Also, how to apply that logic for entire column (means multiple rows of data)? Sorry, I am a newbie to excel formulas.

Comment: Also I want the formula to leave the cell blank if year value is absent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-accurated approach but might help you:

Let´s say you have a column **B** named **Date of birth**, a column **C** named **Today´s date** and a column **D** named **Result in years**. To calculate the aproximated amount of years you need to subtract B from C in order to get an aproximated amount of days and convert this amount in years (365). For example, you have **10/10/1990** as date of birth and **23/09/2016** as today's date but if you subtract them you will get **9480** days that you will have to convert to years by dividing it for 365. The result is **25,97260**, you could read this as almost 26 years and that's why this method is not completely accurate. **Important:** to get the total amount of days you will need to set the cell's format in **Number** or **General**.

Maybe this could help you.
[The procedure in Microsoft Excel 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAWpN.png)